# named Transform in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know I can name an `aggregation` in Pandas, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3],
                   'group' : ['a','a','b']})

    
df.groupby('group').agg(mymean = ('col', 'mean'),
       mymax = ('col', 'max'),
       mymin = ('col', 'min'))

Out[23]: 
       mymean  mymax  mymin
group                      
a         1.5      2      1
b         3.0      3      3
```

This is pretty convenient, as I can create multiple variables and name them on-the-fly. I would like to do the same with a `.transform()` (or an `.apply()`).
Unfortunately, the same trick does not work:

```
df.groupby('group').transform(mymean = ('col', 'mean'),
       mymax = ('col', 'max'),
       mymin = ('col', 'min'))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-3a6cf53bd93e>", line 1, in <module>
    df.groupby('group').transform(mymean = ('col', 'mean'),

TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

What is the most concise way to create multiple variables using a transform? The output should be:

```
Out[25]: 
   col group  mymean  mymax
0    1     a       1      2
1    2     a       1      2
2    3     b       3      3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just do `assign`

```
df.assign(mymean = df['col1'].mean(),mymax = df['col1'].max())
Out[344]: 
   col1  mymean  mymax
0     1     2.0      3
1     2     2.0      3
2     3     2.0      3
```

Comment: holy cow!!! it was that simple? Can `assign` work with a `groupby`?

Comment: let me slightly modify the example accordingly

Comment: hum... I cannot make it work... can you? thanks!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ if chain with groupby I think `df.merge(df.groupby('group').agg().reset_index())` good enough ~

Comment: yes... but I wonder if we might end up getting errors if we have empty groups in the data, thus messing up in the indexes when you call reset_index()

Comment: like `group = [NA, NA, 'a', 'b', 'c']`, I think the NA disappear when you groupby. There is no empty group so to speak

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ then we usually clear the data ...or assign the NA with new unique group